# Jogo da forca com funções em C

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer um jogo da forca em C para ir aprendendo melhor, até porque preciso aprender mais funções tal.
Enquanto o jogo está rodando, eu queria que quando o usuário colocasse uma letra, ele fosse aparecendo lado a lado. E quando errasse também. Exemplo:

Palavra que quero que acerte: `cadeira`

Na tela vai estar `_ _ _ _ _ _ _`
Se o usuário digitar `c`, eu quero que o `c` substitua o primeiro `_`. 
E se ele digitar `W` (que não tem na palavra), eu quero que apareça em baixo dos `_ _ _ _ _ _` uma mensagem, tipo:

```
Erros:
w f g (que são letras que não tem na palavra)
```

Meu código também estava dando erro no `fgets` que como já me explicaram, ele coloca um `\n` na frente da string, mas eu fiz o trim no código pra tirar o `\n`. As primeiras vezes que rodei com o trim no código ele tirou o `\n` e ficou tudo certinho, um do lado do outro. Mas agora que tento rodar o código ele fica igual ficava antes. Assim:

```
_
_
_
_
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque ele fica assim?

Segue o código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char palavra[20];
char forca[20];
char tentativa;
int chances = 5;
int letras, i, j=0, cont;

int start(void)
{

    printf("\nDigite uma palavra: ");
    fgets(palavra, 20, stdin);

    trimEnd(palavra);

    strcpy(forca, palavra);
    letras = strlen(forca);

    for (i=0; i<letras; i++)
    {

        forca[i]=  '_';

    }
}

int jogo(void)
{

    while(chances > 0)
    {

        __fpurge(stdin);
        printf("\nChances: %d - palavras tem %d letras\n\n", chances, letras);

        for (i=0; i<letras; i++)
        {

            printf("\n%c ", forca[i]);

        }

        printf("\n\nDigite uma letra: ");
        scanf("%c", &tentativa);


        cont = 0;

        for (i=0; i<letras; i++)
        {

            if (palavra[i] == tentativa)
            {

                forca[i] == tentativa;
                cont = cont + 1;
                j++;

            }

        }

        if (cont <= 0)
        {

            chances = chances - 1;

        }

        system("clear");

        if (j == letras)
        {

            break;
        }

    }
}

int resultado(void)
{

    if(chances == 0)
    {

        __fpurge(stdin);
        printf("\nChances: %d - palavra tem %d letras\n\n", chances, letras);
        puts(forca);
        printf("\nVocê perdeu. \nA palavra era: ");
        puts(palavra);


    }
    else
    {

        printf("\nParabens, voce acertou a palavra ", chances, letras);
        puts(palavra);

    }

}

void trimEnd(char *str) { //Tira o \n que o fgets lê junto com a variavel pra ir para a ultima linha
    char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    while (end > str && isspace(*end)) end--;
    end++;
    *end = 0;
}

int main()
{

    start();
    system("clear");
    jogo();
    resultado();

    return(0);
}
```

OBS: Só fiz o programa pedir a palavra (o que não faz muito sentido, se eu quero que o usuário digite) porque estou resolvendo esse problema primeiro e quando tudo estiver ok, daí eu vou procurar como fazer para sortear aleatoriamente qualquer palavra que eu tiver dentro de uma matriz, talvez...

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dei uma revisão geral no seu código e ele ficou assim:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char palavra[20];
char forca[20];
char erros[27];

#if defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
#define limpar_input() fflush(stdin)
#define limpar_tela() system("cls")
#else
#include <stdio_ext.h>
#define limpar_input() __fpurge(stdin)
#define limpar_tela() system("clear")
#endif

void limparBuffer(char *buf, int tamanho) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        buf[i] = 0;
    }
}

void trimEnd(char *str) { //Tira o \n que o fgets lê junto com a variavel pra ir para a ultima linha
    int p;
    for (p = strlen(str); isspace(str[p]); p--) {
        str[p] = 0;
    }
}

int ehLetra(char c) {
    return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}

char maiuscula(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ? (c - 32) : c;
}

void start(void) {
    limparBuffer(palavra, 20);
    limparBuffer(forca, 20);
    limparBuffer(erros, 27);

    printf("\nDigite uma palavra: ");
    fgets(palavra, 20, stdin);
    limpar_input();

    trimEnd(palavra);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; palavra[i] != 0; i++) {
        char c = palavra[i];
        forca[i] = ehLetra(c) ? '_' : c;
    }
}

int jogo(void) {
    char tentativa;
    int chances = 5;

    int letras = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; palavra[i] != 0; i++) {
        if (ehLetra(palavra[i])) letras++;
    }

    while (chances > 0) {
        limpar_tela();
        printf("\nChances: %d - palavras tem %d letras\n\n", chances, letras);

        printf("%s", forca);
        if (strlen(erros) > 0) {
            printf("\nErros: %s", erros);
        }

        printf("\n\nDigite uma letra: ");
        scanf("%c", &tentativa);
        limpar_input();

        // Se o usuário digitou algo que não é letra, apenas insiste sem queimar uma chance.
        if (!ehLetra(tentativa)) continue;

        // Se o usuário digitou algo que ele já tentou antes (seja errando ou acertando), apenas insiste sem queimar uma chance.
        int jaTentou = 0;
        for (i = 0; erros[i] != 0; i++) {
            if (erros[i] == maiuscula(tentativa)) {
                jaTentou = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (jaTentou) continue;
        for (i = 0; forca[i] != 0; i++) {
            if (maiuscula(forca[i]) == maiuscula(tentativa)) {
                jaTentou = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (jaTentou) continue;

        int ganhou = 1;
        int achou = 0;
        for (i = 0; palavra[i] != 0; i++) {
            if (!ehLetra(palavra[i])) continue;
            if (forca[i] == '_') {
                if (maiuscula(palavra[i]) == maiuscula(tentativa)) {
                    forca[i] = palavra[i];
                    achou = 1;
                } else {
                    ganhou = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        if (ganhou) {
            return 1; // Ou seja, ganhou.
        }

        if (!achou) {
            chances--;
            erros[strlen(erros)] = maiuscula(tentativa);
        }
    }
    return 0; // Ou seja, perdeu.
}

void mostrarResultado(int resultado) {
    limpar_input();
    if (resultado == 0) {
        printf("\nVoce perdeu. \nA palavra era %s", palavra);
    } else {
        printf("\nParabens, voce acertou a palavra %s ", palavra);
    }
}

int main() {
    start();
    int resultado = jogo();
    mostrarResultado(resultado);
    return 0;
}
```

As mudanças que eu fiz foram:

1. Estou desenvolvendo em um ambiente windows. Por causa disso, para mim ao invés de usar `__fpurge`, devo usar `fflush` e ao invés de `system("clear")`, uso `system("cls")`. Para resolver esse problema, eu uso o seguinte bloco:

   ```c
   #if defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
   #define limpar_input() fflush(stdin)
   #define limpar_tela() system("cls")
   #else
   #include <stdio_ext.h>
   #define limpar_input() __fpurge(stdin)
   #define limpar_tela() system("clear")
   #endif
   ```

   De forma que daí eu tenho as macros `limpar_input` e `limpar_tela` definidas para a chamada correta independente do ambiente de compilação.

   Tal como mencionado [em um comentário pelo Pablo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95977/jogo-da-forca-com-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-em-c/96012#comment194772_96012), usar o `fflush(stdin)` é em geral comportamento indefinido. Entretanto, no windows (que não tem o `__fpurge`), ele é definido. Esse `#if` garante também que o `fflush(stdin)` não será usado em um ambiente que não seja o windows.
2. Esse trecho de código não faz o que você quer:

   ```c
   forca[i] == tentativa;
   ```

   Observe que você usou o igual duplo ao invés do igual simples!
3. A sua lógica tinha alguns sérios problemas: Era possível usar várias vezes a mesma letra sem queimar tentativas, bagunçando com o `j` e podendo ganhar sem achar todas as letras; letras maiúsculas eram consideradas diferentes de minúsculas e palavras que contivessem símbolos que não fossem letras (em especial `_`) podiam fazer o jogo não ficar jogável. Na minha nova lógica, esses problemas são resolvidos.
4. Evite usar `printf` com parâmetros a mais não usados, tal como aqui:

   ```c
   printf("\nParabens, voce acertou a palavra ", chances, letras);
   ```
5. Tente declarar as variáveis no menor escopo possível. Variáveis globais devem ser evitadas sempre que possível. Consegui transformar `tentativa`, `i`, `j`, `chances` e `letras` em variáveis locais. A variável `cont` foi eliminada.
6. Não declare uma função com o tipo de retorno `int` se você não retorna nada dela. Neste caso use `void`.
7. Não há nada de errado em usar aritmética de ponteiros, mas é uma coisa que é bom ser evitada, uma vez que é uma das coisas que fazem com que seja muito fácil fazer besteiras em C. Por causa disso eu reescrevi a sua função `trimEnd` para não usar aritmética de ponteiros.
8. É melhor você ter que limpar algo antes de usar ou limpar após usar? Bem, podemos dizer que vale o ditado "Se sujou, limpe". Por causa disso, coloquei os `limpar_input` (que é o `__fpurge`) logo após o `fgets` e o `scanf`, e não logo antes. Dessa forma o código se preocupa com a limpeza do buffer de entrada após ele ser usado, e não antes. Por outro lado, nos casos onde não é possível ou não é fácil fazer a limpeza após o uso, então convém fazê-la antes do uso, e é por isso que coloquei o `limpar_tela` (que é o `system("clear")`) antes do primeiro `printf` e usei a função `limparBuffer` que criei para limpar `palavra`, `forca` e `erros` antes de seus usos.
9. Para o código pedir apenas letras ao usuário, eu uso a função `ehLetra`. Assim, se a palavra escolhida for `cata-vento` ou alguma outra coisa que contenha alguns símbolos que não são letras, isso não vai causar frustração ou problemas para o jogador.

   Na verificação da letra digitada, o `if (!ehLetra(palavra[i])) continue;` faz com que símbolos especiais sejam ignorados.

   O `forca[i] = ehLetra(c) ? '_' : c;` faz com que os símbolos especiais já apareçam preenchidos quando o jogo começar.

   O `if (ehLetra(palavra[i])) letras++;` garante que apenas as letras da palavra digitada serão contadas.
10. Para evitar frustração, a função `maiuscula` é usada para converter o que o usuário digitar para maiúscula. A finalidade é que letras maiúsculas e minúsculas possam ser aceitas sem diferenciação, o que é alcançado uma vez que a verificação é feita com `if (maiuscula(palavra[i]) == maiuscula(tentativa))`. Por outro lado, como a atribuição ocorre com `forca[i] = palavra[i];`, garante-se que a grafia exibida será a mesma da palavra digitada, independente se o usuário tentou uma letra maiúscula ou minúscula.
11. Ao invés de verificar se o jogador ganhou ou queimou uma chance usando contagem de letras, eu preferi usar as flags `achou` e `ganhou`. A cada iteração, elas são definidas inicialmente como falso e verdadeiro, respectivamente. E então, para cada letra não revelada na resposta, eu faço o seguinte:

    Se a letra digitada pelo usuário coincidir com uma letra não revelada, então isso demonstra que ele descobriu pelo menos uma letra nova que não havia sido achada antes, e portanto `achou` passa para verdadeiro nesse caso.

    Por outro lado, se a letra digitada não coincidir com a letra não revelada, então isso demonstra que há ainda pelo menos uma letra que ainda não foi descoberta, e portanto o `ganhou` passa para falso nesse caso.

    Ao final do laço, se `ganhou` for verdadeiro, então eu já declaro que o jogador ganhou. Caso contrário (`ganhou` é falso) e `achou` também é falso, então é porque ele escolheu uma letra errada, e então queima-se uma tentativa dele e também adiciona-se a letra tentada (e incorreta) no array/string `erros`.
12. Utilizando laços para percorrer strings assim:

    ```c
    for (i = 0; palavra[i] != 0; i++)
    ```

    Eu consigo evitar ter que me preocupar com o tamanho das strings em muitos lugares.
13. Para evitar que o usuário queime tentativas inutilmente ao digitar sem querer algo que não é uma letra, ou que seja uma letra que ele já tentou, eu uso isso:

    ```c
        // Se o usuário digitou algo que não é letra, apenas insiste sem queimar uma chance.
        if (!ehLetra(tentativa)) continue;

        // Se o usuário digitou algo que ele já tentou antes (seja errando ou acertando), apenas insiste sem queimar uma chance.
        int jaTentou = 0;
        for (i = 0; erros[i] != 0; i++) {
            if (erros[i] == maiuscula(tentativa)) {
                jaTentou = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (jaTentou) continue;
        for (i = 0; forca[i] != 0; i++) {
            if (maiuscula(forca[i]) == maiuscula(tentativa)) {
                jaTentou = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (jaTentou) continue;
    ```

    O primeiro laço verifica se a letra é alguma tentativa errada anterior e o segundo se é uma tentativa correta anterior (é errada já tentada antes se estiver em algum lugar dentro de `erros` e correta já tentada antes se estiver em algum lugar de `forca`).
14. O motivo de os seus `_` aparecer um embaixo do outro estava aqui:

    ```c
        for (i=0; i<letras; i++)
        {

            printf("\n%c ", forca[i]);
        }
    ```

    O que faz eles aparecerem um embaixo do outro é o `\n`. No meu código eu coloquei simplesmente isso:

    ```c
        printf("%s", forca);
    ```

    Mas se você preferir, pode usar isso:

    ```c
        for (i = 0; forca[i] != 0; i++) {
            printf("%c ", forca[i]);
        }
    ```

Comment: Cuidado! Você usou fflush num buffer de entrada. Isso é **comportamento indefinido**.

Comment: @Pablo Por isso que ele está protegido pelo `#ifdef`. No windows ele é definido: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx - Veja a parte que diz *`// You must flush the input buffer before using gets.`* - *`// fflush on input stream is an extension to the C standard`*. Realmente, usar `fflush(stdin)` é uma coisa horrível, mas simplesmente não há forma portável de se limpar o `stdin` (e sim, eu pesquisei sobre isso). Se o windows tivesse o `__fpurge` seria um bom começo, mas ele não o tem.

Comment: Não sabia dessa. Explica muita coisa. De qualquer forma, eu costumo usar isso: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26081123/1796236

Comment: Victor Stafusa, muito obrigada. Eu sou iniciante nível básico mesmo e entendi tudo o que você explicou. Claro, vou dar mais algumas lidas pra melhorar meu entendimento... E tentar fazer de acordo com as suas explicações. Muito obrigada mesmo. ;)

Comment: Quando eu começo a ler uma resposta e penso: "Nossa, esse cara se esforçou"; "Nossa, esse cara manja"; "Nossa, eu não conseguiria escrever uma resposta assim"... no final, sempre está escrito: *"Victor Stafusa"*... Wtf!