# O que preciso consertar? [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c

Não estou conseguindo compilar esse código de maneira alguma. Já mexi nos `&'s` dentro dos `scanf's` e `printf's` e nada de mudar o resultado final.

Onde preciso mudar meu código?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main () {

    int peso, altura, idade, necessidadeCal, atividadeInd;
    char sexo[10], atividadeLvl[30];

    printf("Insira seu peso: ");
    scanf("%d", peso);

    printf("\nInsira sua altura: ");
    scanf("%d", altura);

    printf("\nInsira sua idade: ");
    scanf("%d", idade);

    printf("\nInsira seu sexo: ");
    scanf("%s", sexo);

    printf ("\nEm relacao a atividades fisicas, voce se considera: sedentario, levemente ativo, moderadamente ativo, muito ativo ou extremamente ativo? "); 
    scanf ("%s", atividadeLvl[30]);

    if  (atividadeLvl == "sedentario"){
        atividadeInd = 1.25;
    }
        else {
            if  (atividadeLvl == "levemente ativo"){
                atividadeInd = 1.30;
            }
                else {
                    if  (atividadeLvl == "moderadamente ativo"){
                    atividadeInd = 1.50;
                }
                        else {
                            if  (atividadeLvl == "muito ativo"){
                            atividadeInd = 1.70;
                        }
                                else {
                                    if  (atividadeLvl == "extremamente ativo"){
                                        atividadeInd = 2.00;
                                        }}}}}

        if (sexo == "masculino"){
        peso = 66 + 13.7 * peso;
        altura = 5 * altura;
        idade = 6.8 * idade;
    }
    if (sexo == "feminino"){
        peso = 655 + 9.6 * peso;
        altura = 1.7 * altura;
        idade = 4.7 * idade;
    }

    necessidadeCal = (peso + altura - idade) * atividadeInd;
    printf ("\nO seu consumo ideal e de %d calorias diarias", necessidadeCal);
    return 0;
}
```

O erro que dá é o seguinte:

> `C:\Users\Thales\Desktop\Faculdade\PO\Trabalho\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Thales bem vindo ao SOpt, qual o erro que está tendo na saída da compilação?

Comment: [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Primeira coisa que você precisa consertar é a tabulação, assim você vai saber qual else é de cada if. Outra coisa, scanf você usa o '&', quando é inteiro. Programação não é mágica que você vai "mexer nos &" e vai misteriosamente dar certo.

Comment: Feito!! Sua resposta me ajuda muito @bigown... Acrescentei ao código também alguns laços do while para que só dados válidos sejam aceitos. No fim, o código ficou assim:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O código tem vários erros, provavelmente porque está tentando fazer as coisas de forma aleatória. Programação é não é tentativa e erro, é estudar, entender cada aspecto da linguagem, da lógica, do problema e escrever o código sabendo o que está fazendo.

Os dados que são inteiros precisam `&` ([operador "endereço de"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101)) para passar o endereço da variável. Já os tipos que são *strings* (*array* de `char`) não precisam porque essas variáveis já são endereços de memória para o local do objeto (a sequência de caracteres).

Além disto para comparar *strings* usa-se a função [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) e não operador de igualdade que verificará se os endereços apontados são iguais e não se os caracteres são iguais, que é o que deseja.

O código está um pouco desorganizado. Não precisa de tantos `if`, use o `else if` para simplificar. Tem outras coisas que podem ser melhoradas. Não sei se a lógica está correta.

Tem maneiras melhores de resolver o problema, mas não quis mexer demais no código.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    int peso, altura, idade, necessidadeCal, atividadeInd;
    char sexo[10], atividadeLvl[30];
    printf("Insira seu peso: ");
    scanf("%d", &peso);
    printf("\nInsira sua altura: ");
    scanf("%d", &altura);
    printf("\nInsira sua idade: ");
    scanf("%d", &idade);
    printf("\nInsira seu sexo: ");
    scanf("%s", sexo);
    printf ("\nEm relacao a atividades fisicas, voce se considera: sedentario, levemente ativo, moderadamente ativo, muito ativo ou extremamente ativo? "); 
    scanf ("%s", atividadeLvl);
    if  (strcmp(atividadeLvl, "sedentario") == 0) {
        atividadeInd = 1.25;
    } else if (strcmp(atividadeLvl, "levemente ativo") == 0) {
        atividadeInd = 1.30;
    } else if (strcmp(atividadeLvl, "moderadamente ativo") == 0) {
        atividadeInd = 1.50;
    } else if (strcmp(atividadeLvl, "muito ativo") == 0) {
        atividadeInd = 1.70;
    }  else if (strcmp(atividadeLvl, "extremamente ativo") == 0) {
        atividadeInd = 2.00;
    }
    if (strcmp(sexo, "masculino") == 0) {
        peso = 66 + 13.7 * peso;
        altura *= 5;
        idade *= 6.8;
    } else if (strcmp(sexo, "feminino") == 0) {
        peso = 655 + 9.6 * peso;
        altura *= 1.7;
        idade *= 4.7;
    }
    necessidadeCal = (peso + altura - idade) * atividadeInd;
    printf ("\nO seu consumo ideal e de %d calorias diarias", necessidadeCal);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/N4uZRD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/icgpwmhm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/HumanActivity.c).

Comment: Muito muito obrigado!! As sugestões são extremamente bem vindas... Ainda não tenho tanta familiaridade com programação, então, ainda tá saindo de forma rudimentar.

Não conhecia a função de comparação entre strings e nem essa sintaxe para multiplicação...

O código compilou aqui e vou buscar melhorar a organização dos códigos futuros

Answer (score 6):

O seu código tem um monte de erros.

Primeiramente, o `scanf` recebe como segundo parâmetro um endereço de memória. Por exemplo, isso está certo:

```
scanf("%d", &peso);
```

Isso não está:

```
scanf("%d", peso);
```

Lembre-se que em C, arrays são em muitos lugares equivalentes a ponteiros. Portanto isso está certo:

```
scanf("%s", atividadeLvl);
```

E isso não está:

```
scanf("%s", &atividadeLvl);
```

E nem isso:

```
scanf ("%s", atividadeLvl[30]);
```

Entretanto, mesmo assim, o `scanf` não vai fazer o que você quer, pois ele vai para no primeiro espaço, e não vai ser capaz de ler algo como `levemente ativo`.

Além disso, o operador `==` quando aplicado a strings que são arrays de caraceters, vai comparar se o endereço das strings é o mesmo e não se o conteúdo é o mesmo. Isso não vai dar certo. Para isso existe a função `strcmp` que fazem comparações de strings. O `strcmp` faz a comparação lexicográfica (mais ou menos, ordem alfabética, mas com ordenação definida pela tabela ASCII onde letras maiúsculas vem antes de minúsculas). Ele retorna 0 quando as strings forem iguais, -1 se a primeira antecede a segunda ou 1 se a primeira sucede a segunda.

Além disso, você declara varias variáveis como `int`, ou seja, inteiro, mas as multiplica por valores de ponto flutuante tais como `1.25`. Por este motivo, você deve usar `float` ou `double`.

E evite encadear os `else`s muito profundamente. Use o `else if` para ficar mais simples.

E você não precisa de `#include<conio.h>`. Mas vai precisar de `#include<string.h>`.

Pegando um pouco do código emprestado [dessa minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96012/132) para solucionar o problema do `scanf`, eis o código resultante:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#if defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
#define limpar_input() fflush(stdin)
#else
#define limpar_input() __fpurge(stdin)
#endif

void trim_end(char *str) {
    int p;
    for (p = strlen(str); isspace(str[p]); p--) {
        str[p] = 0;
    }
}

int main() {

    double peso, altura, idade, necessidadeCal, atividadeInd;
    char sexo[10], atividadeLvl[30];

    printf("Insira seu peso: ");
    scanf("%lf", &peso);

    printf("\nInsira sua altura: ");
    scanf("%lf", &altura);

    printf("\nInsira sua idade: ");
    scanf("%lf", &idade);
    limpar_input();

    printf("\nInsira seu sexo: ");
    fgets(sexo, 10, stdin);
    limpar_input();
    trim_end(sexo);

    printf("\nEm relacao a atividades fisicas, voce se considera: sedentario, levemente ativo, moderadamente ativo, muito ativo ou extremamente ativo? ");
    fgets(atividadeLvl, 30, stdin);
    limpar_input();
    trim_end(atividadeLvl);

    if (strcmp(atividadeLvl, "sedentario") == 0) {
        atividadeInd = 1.25;
    } else if (strcmp(atividadeLvl, "levemente ativo") == 0) {
        atividadeInd = 1.30;
    } else if (strcmp(atividadeLvl, "moderadamente ativo") == 0) {
        atividadeInd = 1.50;
    } else if (strcmp(atividadeLvl, "muito ativo") == 0) {
        atividadeInd = 1.70;
    } else if (strcmp(atividadeLvl, "extremamente ativo") == 0) {
        atividadeInd = 2.00;
    } else {
        printf("Que chato, voce nao informou algo legal.");
        return 1;
    }

    if (strcmp(sexo, "masculino") == 0) {
        peso = 66 + 13.7 * peso;
        altura = 5 * altura;
        idade = 6.8 * idade;
    } else if (strcmp(sexo, "feminino") == 0) {
        peso = 655 + 9.6 * peso;
        altura = 1.7 * altura;
        idade = 4.7 * idade;
    } else {
        printf("Que chato, voce nao informou algo legal.");
        return 1;
    }

    necessidadeCal = (peso + altura - idade) * atividadeInd;
    printf("\nO seu consumo ideal e de %lf calorias diarias", necessidadeCal);
    return 0;
}
```