# Descobrir o sistema operacional da máquina em C

Tags: c

Preciso fazer uma função para limpar a tela em C que rode no Windows, no Mac e no Linux. Pensei em fazer uma função que:

Se o SO fosse Windows: `system("cls");`

Se o SO fosse Linux ou Mac: `system("clear");`

O problema é: Como faço pra descobrir o sistema operacional do computador e como seria esses `if` e `else`?

Comment: Da uma olhada http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system

Comment: Acho melhor você criar um programa para cada SO. Se você for fazer tudo junto, vai ficar mais pesado e confuso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para saberes se o sistema é linux ou windows podes fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
#ifdef __unix__         
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32) 

   #define OS_Windows

   #include <windows.h>

#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
#ifdef OS_Windows
 /* Codigo Windows */
    system("cls");
#else
 /* Codigo GNU/Linux */
    system("clear");
#endif    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96012/132), eu usei isso:

```c
#if defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
#define limpar_input() fflush(stdin)
#define limpar_tela() system("cls")
#else
#include <stdio_ext.h>
#define limpar_input() __fpurge(stdin)
#define limpar_tela() system("clear")
#endif
```

Comment: Eu normalmente procuro pela definição de `WIN32` ou `_WIN32`.  Também uso mais o Visual Studio do que o `MingW` para programar