# Variável int muda de valor ao realizar a leitura de uma variável char

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um jogo de forca simples. Porém, quando realizo a leitura da letra (seja com `gets` ou com `scanf`), a quantidade de vidas cai para 0. Estou usando o Dev-C++, pois é o programa que o professor usa em classe.

```
int main() {

    int i, vida = 3;
    char letra[1], resposta[30] = "azul", segredo[4] = "----";


    do{
        printf("Vidas: %d\t", vida);
        printf("%s\n\n", segredo);

        printf("________________________\n\n");

        printf("Digite uma letra: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(letra);

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(resposta); i++){
            if(letra[0] == resposta[i]){
                segredo[i] = resposta[i];
            }
        }

        system("cls");
    }while(strcmp(resposta, segredo) != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nunca, jamais, em hipótese nenhuma ouse usar a função `gets`. Essa função horrorosa é odiada por programadores em C por um bom motivo: É impossível utilizá-la corretamente e todas e quaisquer formas de se utilizar `gets` são erradas. O motivo disso é que ela começa a escrever uma string em uma área de memória, mas sem se preocupar em saber onde essa área termina, o que resulta em corrupção da memória do programa.

A função `gets` foi por muitos anos considerada obsoleta. A partir do padrão do C de 2011, ela foi removida para não voltar nunca mais (embora o GCC ainda a reconheça). Já vai tarde!

Entretanto, o seu maior problema é que você não tem espaço para o terminador nulo no array `segredo`. Resolvendo-se esse problema e usando-se `scanf` ao invés de `gets`, o seu programa funciona. Além disso, o seu `fflush(stdin)` e o `system("cls")` não são portáveis, o que pode ser resolvido com base [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231870/132).

Veja o resultado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#if defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
#define limpar_input() fflush(stdin)
#define limpar_tela() system("cls")
#else
#define limpar_input() __fpurge(stdin)
#define limpar_tela() system("clear")
#endif

int main() {

    int i, vida = 3;
    char letra;
    char resposta[30] = "azul", segredo[30] = "----";

    do {
        printf("Vidas: %d\t", vida);
        printf("%s\n\n", segredo);

        printf("________________________\n\n");

        printf("Digite uma letra: ");
        scanf("%c", &letra);
        limpar_input();

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(resposta); i++) {
            if (letra == resposta[i]) {
                segredo[i] = resposta[i];
            }
        }

        limpar_tela();
    } while (strcmp(resposta, segredo) != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Ah, e o Dev-C++ é um dinossauro também. Use uma IDE mais moderna se possível, tal como o Code::Blocks, o Eclipse, o Netbeans ou o Visual Studio.

E lembre-se:

## NUNCA USE `gets`

- Sempre que `gets` é usado, um bebê baleia morre intoxicado por lixo radioativo.
- Usar `gets` pode causar doenças de pele, perda de cabelo, fraturas, degeneração muscular, câncer, cegueira, fadiga, hepatite, imunodeficiência, distúrbios alimentares, ataques psicóticos, alucinações, distúrbios psico-motores e diversos problemas cardíacos, renais, respiratórios, circulatórios, hepáticos, cognitivos e comportamentais (ao menos é isso que você pode adquirir ao ter que fazer debug de programas grandes que usam `gets`).
- O `gets` é algo perigoso e pode viciar no primeiro uso. Não existe nível seguro para o uso de `gets`.
- Viva a vida em sua plenitude! Diga não ao `gets`! Diga não às drogas!