# Item de lista causando erro no programa C

Tags: c, dev-c++

Boa noite pessoal.

Estou tendo problema com um código simples, pra um trabalho da faculdade no qual não consigo descobrir o porque do erro, já que o Dev-C++ não reporta nenhum erro. Pra evitar que alguém da minha faculdade ache esse tópico por acaso e copie meu código, vou usar um de exemplo do próprio professor, com a adição do que tá dando erro no meu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAM 3

typedef struct{
    int cod;
    char nome[50];
    char telefone[20];
} tipo_pessoa;

int main(){
    tipo_pessoa lista[TAM];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<TAM; i++){
        printf("Insira o nome da pessoa %d:\n", i+1);
        gets(lista[i].nome);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Insira o telefone de pessoa %d (XX XXXXX XXXX):\n", i+1);
        gets(lista[i].telefone);
        fflush(stdin);
        lista[i].cod = i+1;
    }       
    system("cls");
    printf("Os cadastros foram preenchidos...\n\n");
    system("pause");
    for(i=0; i<TAM; i++){
        printf("%s - %s - %s\n", lista[i].cod, lista[i].nome, lista[i].telefone);
    }
}
```

O meu problema é com o `lista[i].cod`, que ao tenta "imprimir" na tela, o programa finaliza na hora. Se eu tirar o `lista[i].cod` do `printf`, o código roda normalmente. Se eu pedir pro usuário especificar o numero, ele retorna um caractere estranho, mas ainda sim, eu preciso que o código seja gerado automaticamente pelo `system` e preciso que ele seja exibido no `printf`.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Me desculpem se for algo idiota que eu não esteja vendo, mas eu estou há 4 horas batendo cabeça nisso.

Comment: Dev-C++ é um dinossauro, está abandonado há muito tempo. Há muitas outras IDEs para desenvolvimento em C mais modernas.

Comment: Nunca use a função `gets`. NUNCA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%d` ao invés de `%s` para imprimir códigos numéricos:

```
 printf("%d - %s - %s\n", lista[i].cod, lista[i].nome, lista[i].telefone);
```

Ou seja, o primeiro `%s` era para ser um `%d`.

Além disso, nunca use a função `gets`. No lugar disso:

```
gets(lista[i].nome);
```

Use isso:

```
fgets(lista[i].nome, 50, stdin);
```

No lugar disso:

```
gets(lista[i].telefone);
```

Use isso:

```
fgets(lista[i].telefone, 20, stdin);
```

Os motivos para não usar `gets` eu explico [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254693/132) e também falo sobre ela [nesta outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282265/132).

Também tome cuidado com o `fflush(stdin)`. Veja mais sobre isso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231882/132) e [nessa outra também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96012/132).

Por fim, o Dev-C++ é uma ide bem antiga e há muito tempo já abandonada. Procure uma outra ide para C mais moderna, tal como o Code::Blocks, o NetBeans, o Visual Studio, etc.

Comment: Eu uso o Visual Studio pra outras linguagens, só to usando o Dev-C++ pra esse trabalho específicamente pra usar os gets e etc. Sei dos problemas dele, mas é o que o professor ta usando agora no começo do módulo, e ele pede isso no enunciado.

E pra variar, eu comedi um erro idiota em relação ao %d e %s, infelizmente.

Comment: @MaxPresi Pedir `gets` no enunciado é pra matar. Essa droga de função nunca deveria ter sido inventada, então pedir para os alunos usarem ela é ensinar errado.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d - %s - %s\n", lista[i].cod, lista[i].nome, lista[i].telefone);
```

`lista[i].cod` é um inteiro, então você tem que colocar um `%d` pra indicar que vai ser escrito um inteiro e não um `%s` de "string".