# Problemas com uma função de validação de datas em C

Tags: c

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para cadastros de pacientes. É um projeto da faculdade. Estou dividindo grupos de funções em arquivos diferentes. Acontece que criei uma função para validar o cadastro de data, a função funciona mas não registra o último valor digita que seria o correto.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "validacoes.h"

void validaData(int valor, int x, int y, char data[4]){
if(valor < x || valor > y){
        do{
            printf("%s não existente, digite um %s válido! \n", data, data);
            printf("%s: ", data);
            scanf("%d", &valor);
            printf("%d \n", valor);
        }while(valor < x || valor > y);
    };
}
```

Esse é o arquivo da função:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pacientes.h"
#include "validacoes.h"

typedef struct {
        int dia;
        int mes;
        int ano;
} data;
typedef struct {
        char rua[30];
        char bairro[30];
        char cidade[30];
        char estado[3];
        char cep[10];
} endereco;
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char nome[30];
    char email[30];
    char cpf[15];
    char telefone[15];
    //char comorbidade;
    data dataNascimento;
    endereco enderecoPaciente;
} cadastro;

cadastro paciente[100];   
void registro(){    

fflush(stdin);
        printf("Data de nascimento \n");
        printf("Dia: ");
        scanf("%d", &paciente[i].dataNascimento.dia);
        validaData(paciente[i].dataNascimento.dia, 1, 31, "Dia");
        printf("Mês: ");
        scanf("%d", &paciente[i].dataNascimento.mes);
        validaData(paciente[i].dataNascimento.mes, 1, 12, "Mes");
        printf("Ano: ");
        scanf("%d", &paciente[i].dataNascimento.ano);
        validaData(paciente[i].dataNascimento.ano, 1900, 2020, "Ano");
        system("Pause");
 }
```

A função `registro` é onde a função `validaData` deveria funcionar.

No entanto, quando estou fazendo o cadastro, a função `validaData` consegue pegar o valor caso digitado fora dos parâmetros passado na função. Mas quando ele termina de executar, com a digitação correta do valor, o que fica guardado na variável `paciente[i].dataNascimento.dia` é o primeiro valor digitado antes de passar pela validação.

Alguém saberia como resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O parâmetro `valor` da função `validaData` é passado por valor. Assim sendo, quando você faz `scanf("%d", &valor);`, você vai mudar apenas o valor da variável local `valor`, mas isso não vai alterar o conteúdo de `paciente[i].dataNascimento.dia`, nem de `paciente[i].dataNascimento.mes` e nem de `paciente[i].dataNascimento.ano`. O certo seria a função `validaData` retornar o novo valor lido.

Um outro detalhe é que uma função chamada `validaData` deveria, dado o seu nome fazer apenas a validação. Mas ela não está fazendo isso, ela está fazendo a releitura caso a data esteja incorreta. Uma abordagem mais robusta seria fazer a função para ler a data e reler quantas vezes forem necessárias até que a data informada seja válida.

Há uma questão de validação também que o seu código aceita datas inválidas tais como 31/04/2020 ou 29/02/2021, pois nem todos os meses tem os dias 29, 30 e 31.

Além disso, há o caso de o usuário responder `xyz` quando for perguntado o dia, e isso vai confundir o `scanf`. Como isso é um projeto de faculdade, o melhor é ler o que o usuário digitar sem fazer nenhum tipo de presunção sobre o que ele digitar e então tentar construir uma data com isso.

Outra coisa é que o `fflush(stdin)` só funciona no windows. Veja [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231882/132) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96012/132) respostas explicando como resolver.

De fato, a função `scanf` é uma função arcana, arcaica e difícil de se utilizar corretamente e os seus maiores problemas se originam disso. Essa função não deveria mais ser usada. Veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58403537/540552) explicações sobre o porquê de não usá-la e o que usar em seu lugar.

Assim sendo, sugiro essa função para ler uma data:

```c
// Autor: Victor Stafusa - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
} data;

// Veja mais sobre isso nesses links:
// https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231882/132
// https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96012/132
#if defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
#define limpar_input() fflush(stdin)
#else
#include <stdio_ext.h>
#define limpar_input() __fpurge(stdin)
#endif

// Monta um número de 2 dígitos a partir de 2 chars.
#define numero2(a, b) \
    ( (a - '0') * 10 \
    + (b - '0'))

// Monta um número de 4 dígitos a partir de 4 chars.
#define numero4(a, b, c, d) \
    ( (a - '0') * 1000 \
    + (b - '0') * 100 \
    + (c - '0') * 10 \
    + (d - '0'))

// Verifica se a string dada tem um formato NN/NN/NNNN.
// Mas não verifica nada após o 10o caractere.
int validarFormatoData(const char *digitado) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char c = digitado[i];
        if ((i == 2 || i == 5) ? c != '/' : (c < '0' || c > '9')) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Descobre quantos dias há no mês de um determinado ano.
int diasNoMes(int mes, int ano) {
    // São bissextos os anos divisíveis por 4,
    // com exceção dos que terminam com 00 e não são divisíveis por 400.
    int bissexto = (ano % 4 == 0 && ano % 100 != 0) || ano % 400 == 0;

    // Tabela com os dias de cada mês.
    // Observe que fevereiro varia dependendo se o ano for ou não bissexto.
    // Observe que a posição zero não é usada porque não há mês zero.
    int dias[] = {0, 31, bissexto ? 29 : 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    return dias[mes];
}

// Descobre se a data do meio de fato está entre a data mínima e a máxima.
int comparaData3(const data *min, const data *meio, const data *max) {
    // Monta um inteiro para cada data na forma AAAAMMDD.
    int a = min->ano * 10000 + min->mes * 100 + min->dia;
    int b = meio->ano * 10000 + meio->mes * 100 + meio->dia;
    int c = max->ano * 10000 + max->mes * 100 + max->dia;

    // Como as datas foram reduzidos a números inteiros,
    // fica fácil saber se estão na ordem correta.
    return a <= b && b <= c;
}

// Lê uma data do usuário no formato DD/MM/AAAA.
// Insiste até que uma data válida seja digitada.
// Inclui uma mensagem que pede para o usuário digitar alguma coisa.
// Inclui uma mensagem de erro para o caso de o usuário digitar algo inválido.
// Inclui as datas mínimas e máximas permitidas.
data lerData(const char *mensagem, const char *erro, const data *min, const data *max) {
    char digitado[12];
    int primeiraVez = 1;

    // Repete quantas vezes for necessário, a menos que o return seja alcançado. 
    while (1) {
        // Se não for a primeira vez, então é porque a vez anterior deu errado e uma
        // mensagem de erro deve ser mostrada.
        if (primeiraVez) {
            primeiraVez = 0;
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", erro);
        }

        // Mostra a mensagem e lê o que o usuário digitar.
        printf("%s", mensagem);
        fgets(digitado, 12, stdin);
        limpar_input(); // Limpa o input se ficou sujeira nele.

        // Se os 10 primeiros caracteres não estiverem no formato NN/NN/NNNN,
        // então a data é inválida. E se houver algo depois desse NN/NN/NNNN, ela
        // também é.
        if (!validarFormatoData(digitado) || digitado[10] != '\n') continue;

        // Se chegou aqui, então a data tem um formato válido, o que ainda não
        // necessariamente significa que ela é válida. Nesse ponto já podemos
        // obter o número do dia, do mês e do ano ao montar inteiros a partir dos
        // caracteres digitados.
        int dia = numero2(digitado[0], digitado[1]);
        int mes = numero2(digitado[3], digitado[4]);
        int ano = numero4(digitado[6], digitado[7], digitado[8], digitado[9]);

        // Verifica se o dia e o mês são válidos.
        // Inclusive, graças a função diasNoMes, verifica se o mês tem 30 ou 31
        // dias ou sse for fevereiro, se o ano é bissexto ou não.
        if (mes < 1 || mes > 12 || dia < 1 || dia > diasNoMes(mes, ano)) continue;

        // A data é válida. Podemos construí-la.
        data d = {dia, mes, ano};

        // Verifica se que a data montada está entre a data mínima e a máxima.
        if (!comparaData3(min, &d, max)) continue;

        // Se chegou até aqui, a data está ok.
        return d;
    };
}

// Teste do código todo.
// Pede para digitar uma data, insistindo até que uma data válida seja digitada
// e então exibe essa data.
int main(void) {
    data min = {1, 1, 1900};
    data max = {31, 12, 2020};
    data d = lerData(
        "Digite a data de nascimento (DD/MM/AAAA): ",
        "Essa data não estava certa. Vamos tentar novamente.",
        &min,
        &max);
    printf("A data que você digitou foi %d/%d/%d.", d.dia, d.mes, d.ano);
    return 0;
}
```

Os comentários no código explicam o que ele está fazendo. Basicamente, ele te dará uma função `lerData` que vai pedir para o usuário digitar uma data e vai insistir até o usuário digitar uma data válida.

[**Veja aqui o código funcionando no repl.it.**](https://repl.it/repls/DecentDeliciousText#main.c)

Comment: Muito bom! 133 linhas de código, validação do tamanho do mês, anos bissextos, etc. Sempre que vejo essas soluções para problemas universitários minha apreciação por APIs modernas de *Date/Time* é renovada.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Tem o [`struct tm`](http://zetcode.com/articles/cdatetime/) que seria o melhor tipo de dado já pré-fabricado para isso com várias funções de biblioteca já prontas que o manipulam. No entanto, utilizá-lo corretamente também traz seus desafios e complicações. Foi por causa de tanto conviver com esse tipo de situação utilizando tanta coisa de baixo nível em C e tendo que todo dia reinventar a roda quadrada, que acabei me especializando em Java e agora em Python. 

Comment: @VictorStafusa Mano, muito obrigado, me ajudou muito.